# How do I get RStudio to publish R-markdown to the rpubs.org site?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

According to [a response from the RStudio team](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/666-how-do-i-publish-to-rpubs), the "standard" solution would be to [follow the instructions for "Using R Markdown with RStudio"](http://www.rstudio.org/docs/authoring/using_markdown), and notice the button on the third screenshot with the "Publish" button. A wonderfully simple solution that I'm quite grateful they have built.

However, the "Publish" button with the nice arrow and picture of the earth doesn't show up in my preview window, no matter how badly I want it to.

I am using RStudio (`RStudio.version()` 0.96.231) in Mac OS X Lion (10.7), with latest R version and updated `markdown` and `knitr` packages. I have an RPubs account, and have followed [the RPubs instructions for creating and previewing the html rendered from an R markdown file](http://www.rpubs.com/about/getting-started) from within RStudio.

This seems to be related to a post on the [RStudio support blog about not-seeing a Publish button](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/2513-problem-with-publish-to-rpubs-windows-rstudio-096231).

However, this question is different, as it requires actually getting content up onto [RPubs](http://www.rpubs.com/). I have posted an [analogous question on the RStudio Support blog](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/666-how-do-i-publish-to-rpubs).

The Rstudio team already answered [how to get graphics embedded in html rendered by RStudio from R Markdown source](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/664-how-do-i-get-graphics-embedded-in-rpubs-published-from-rstudio); especially by pointing me to this extremely useful page explaining the way RStudio renders and packages [R Markdown](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markdown/index.html) using [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/):

[Using RStudio to render R Markdown](http://www.rstudio.org/docs/authoring/using_markdown)

Finally, if you haven't heard about R-markdown (I just learned of it),
go here for [details about R-markdown](http://www.r-bloggers.com/announcing-the-r-markdown-package/).

Comment: There is not much we can do to help here at this point since rpubs.com is so new. Your best bet is to file a bug at rstudio. But yeah, `knitr` and markdown aren't new and you can always post knitted markdown to github.

Comment: Just to check, exactly what version of RStudio are you running? Is it 0.96.230 or later?

Comment: RStudio.version()
[1] "0.96.231"

Comment: RStudio team responded on [their blog-discussion of this issue](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/666-how-do-i-publish-to-rpubs): "that looks like it is related to Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion). We'll be looking into this". Sounds like a fix will come soon, and might be simply an OS-related bug. I thought at first there might be some obscure implementation related step I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed by Josh Paulson at RStudio, this [was a bug with RStudio in OS X Lion](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/666-how-do-i-publish-to-rpubs) and not some weird extra set of unstated dependencies or unclear instructions.

Just install v0.96.233 or greater and this should work on Mac OS X Lion (10.7).

Actually, [the implementation and instructions](http://www.rstudio.org/docs/authoring/using_markdown) are quite straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I removed the op-ed comment. I'm considering pulling-down this question because it turned out to be uninteresting (update your version).